# Find formula for $\sum_{k = 1}^{n}(k^2 \cdot x^{k - 1})$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

It is almost obvious that we have to use derivative in order to find the answer. However, I couldn't see this one to be derivative of something.

It would be amazing if you share your thoughts on this problem. Also, I would be thankful if you would explain what was intuition behind your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^nx^k,$$ so that $$
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\sum_{k=1}^n kx^{k-1}\\
xf'(x)&=\sum_{k=1}^n kx^k\\
f'(x)+xf''(x)&=\sum_{k=1}^n k^2x^k\\
\end{align}$$

Now just evaluate $f(x)$ and fill in the details.

Answer (score 0):

*An old trick !*
$$S=\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k^2 \, x^{k - 1}=\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\big[k(k-1)+k \big]\, x^{k - 1}$$ that is to say
$$S=\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k(k-1) \, x^{k - 1}+\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k \, x^{k - 1}$$
$$S=x\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k(k-1) \, x^{k - 2}+\sum_{k = 1}^{n}k \, x^{k - 1}$$
$$S=x \left(\sum_{k = 1}^{n}x^k \right)''+\left(\sum_{k = 1}^{n}x^k \right)'$$